# ansi colors not displaying in emacs window

Tags: python, emacs, colors, ansi-escape

I know that variants of this question have been asked before... but I must be having a different problem because the solutions aren't working for me. I've got a text file that uses ANSI codes which display nicely when I `cat` the file to the terminal. When I emacs 23.2.1 the file however, I see things like this:

```
^[[36mText^[[0m
```

If it matters, the `^[` are both red in that line (emacs is treating that as one character) and the rest of that text is black. I expect that line to be light blue in the emacs editor. It might be helpful to mention that I'm making this file with the python code

```
python
>>> myfile = open("test.txt","w")
>>> myfile.write("\033[36mText\033[0m\n")
>>> myfile.close()
```

to generate that text. Looking around, I tried several solutions:

```
(require 'ansi-color)                                                                                                                                                                                              
;(autoload 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on "ansi-color" nil t)                                                                                                                                                      

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)                                                                                                                                                         

;(setq ansi-term-color-vector [unspecified "#3f3f3f" "#cc9393" "#7f9f7f" "#f0dfaf"  "#8cd0d3" "#dc8cc3" "#93e0e3" "#dcdccc"]) 

;(defun colorize-compilation-buffer ()                                                                                                                                                                             
;  (toggle-read-only)                                                                                                                                                                                              
;  (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))                                                                                                                                                            
;  (toggle-read-only))                                                                                                                                                                                             
;(add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'colorize-compilation-buffer)                                                                                                                                                  

;(defadvice display-message-or-buffer (before ansi-color activate)                                                                                                                                                 
;  "Process ANSI color codes in shell output."                                                                                                                                                                     
;  (let ((buf (ad-get-arg 0)))                                                                                                                                                                                     
;    (and (bufferp buf)                                                                                                                                                                                            
;         (string= (buffer-name buf) "*Shell Command Output*")                                                                                                                                                     
;         (with-current-buffer buf                                                                                                                                                                                 
;           (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))))))
```

But none of these worked. I'm not an emacs/lisp expert... so I'm pretty helpless on my own here. I also tried clearing everything else in my `.emacs` file just in case there were conflicts.

Any other ideas on what I could try?

Comment: Maybe refer to the answer that was not working, should help people with knowing what NOT to answer.

Comment: none of the solutions I found were working. the solutions text i pasted shows the different things i tried and then commented out (the uncommented solution doesn't work either).

Comment: Can you attach the file?  What major mode does Emacs choose when you open the file in it?  Have you tried M-x ansi-term?  (I doubt it would work on its own, but it might form part of a solution.)

Comment: The python snippet I provided creates a test file. It's opening in Text mode. Yes, if I open an `ansi-term` I can navigate to the file, `cat` it, and I see the color.